# Angular 8 hybrid app not recognizes AngularJS components

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I started developing a hybrid application. So I have done th folllowing steps:

- add Angular 8 dependencies
- add `polyfills.ts`
- remove `ng-app` attribute from my root index.html
- do a manual bootstrap of AngularJs app

How looks my Angular init module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ]
})
export class HubAngularModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() {
    }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(HubAngularModule)
    .then(platformRef => {
        console.log("Bootstrapping in Hybrid mode with Angular & AngularJS");
        const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;

        upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myAngularJsModule']);
    });
```

How looks my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="dist/index.bundle.js"></script> <!--Webpack bundle-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div layout="column" layout-align="" ng-cloak>
    <main-header></main-header> <!--AngularJS header component-->
    <console-menu></console-menu> <!--AngularJS menu component-->
    <md-content ui-view="main"></md-content> <!--AngularJS root ui-view-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main-header, console-menu - are AngularJS components. Of course that configuration works well when `ng-app` is presented.

What I expect. Hybrid app starts just like old AngularJS app and I'm able to see login page, start page etc.

What I actually got. AngularJS app is actually bootstrapping. I can see method app.module().run(...) executes. But no component loads so I see only a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a several hours of experiments I have found a soultion.
I decided to check whether the manual bootstrap of the AngularJS will work:

```
angular.element(document)
    .ready(() => {
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myAngularJsModule']);
    });
```

And it had failed. Even if no Angular 8 present. So the reason it fails to start is a location of `<script>` tags with my webpack bundles. It located in `<head>` but should be located in `<body>` after all the app markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<div layout="column" layout-align="" ng-cloak>
    <main-header></main-header> <!--AngularJS header component-->
    <console-menu></console-menu> <!--AngularJS menu component-->
    <md-content ui-view="main"></md-content> <!--AngularJS root ui-view-->
</div>
<script src="dist/index.bundle.js"></script> <!--Webpack bundle-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles.css"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It is so dumb, but exactly that dumb thing like this make the biggest headache sometimes. And what disappointed me me the most not a single migration tutorial tells nothing about that detail!

Comment: Holy heck, thank you for this. The things people assume the reader knows, I guess! Now that the hybrid is finally working, I can move on to the fun part, upgrading all the things :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded your angularJS components to make them work in Angular ?

Comment: Answer depends on what is 'upgrade" means. All my components are exactly Components. They defined like angular.module().component and written on Typescript.

Comment: If you can provide a stackblitz, I can help you better, What I was mentioning above  was have you used upgrade component in angularJs component something like this ?            ` export class AngularJSComponent extends UpgradeComponent {
  

  @Input() twoWay: number;
  @Output() twoWayChange: EventEmitter<number>;

  constructor(ref: ElementRef, inj: Injector) {
    super('angularjsComponent', ref, inj);
  } `
}

Comment: No i didn't do it. My app has near 120 AngularJS components (.ts files). Does it mean I have to apply UpgradeComponent to all of them to just a start an application? It is just a madness.